# Retrieving data value from database from ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax function that would retrieve data from my database and display it in my textbox. I am using a [JQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) to shorten the ajax process a little bit. Now what I want to do is to get the data back from the php script that I called from the ajax function.

The form markup is:

```
<form action="searchFunction.php" method="post" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="searchStudent" id="searchStudent" class="searchTextbox" />
  <input type="submit" name="Search" id="Search" value="Search" class="searchButton" />
</form>
```

Server code in `searchFunction.php`

```
$cardid = $_POST['searchStudent'] ;
$cardid = mysql_real_escape_string($cardid);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `card_id` = '$cardid'") or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

return $row;
```

The ajax script that processes the php is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchForm').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: processSearch
  });
});

function processSearch(data) {
  alert(data['username']); //Am I doing it right here?
}
```

In PHP, if I want to call the data, I would just simply create a function for the database and just for example `echo $row['username']` it. But how do I do this with ajax? I'm fairly new to this so, please explain the process.

Comment: Redirect ajax to a php page and do database retrieve part there, and in success function receive the response

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#Search').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <------------------ stop default behaviour of button
    var element = this;    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/<SolutionName>/<MethodName>",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData}),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function () {
                    alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
                },
                 success: processSearch,
    });
});
 function processSearch(data) {
var username= ($(data).find('#username'));
```

}

Comment: What does `<SolutionName>/<MethodName>` mean? should I put the path to the `searchFunction.php` or there is anything should I put there?

Comment: As per your code the method name is "searchStudent" and solution name is "sitename"

Comment: I have tried to implement your code, but when I click on the button it redirects to blank `searchFunction.php ` instead of doing the process "background" and display the alert? Plus the alert is also not showing up?

Comment: In url you can give like this::  url:"searchStudent.php",

Comment: Thank your for your quick response, I have changed everything that you changed and tried to `alert(username);` But it still fails to do so. The page keeps reloading when the button is pressed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Change the input type submit to button. Submit will trigger the action in the form so the form will get reloaded. if you are performing an ajax call change it into button.

Comment: Changed it to button. But still nothing works. I even tried to invoke error if the path is incorrect. But I got no alerts in giving me the error.

Comment: First write alert('button pressed ') before ajax call to check whether the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be fine, except this bit -

```
function processSearch(data) {
   alert(data['username']); //Am I doing it right here?
}
```

You need to change it to -

```
function processSearch(data) {
   // data is a JSON object. Need to access it with dot notation
   alert(data.username);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You also need to return a JSON response from your PHP file. Something like -

```
// Set the Content Type to JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = [
    "key" => "value"
];

return json_encode($data);
```

In your case you can directly encode the `$row` like so -

```
return json_encode($row);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you give some example for the JSON response? Should I do it like this `'username' => $row['username'];` ?

Comment: I have changed it, but still, no alert is showing up? Or at least if the ajax is not working the alert should popup with blank values. But now it's just not showing any alert when the button is clicked. Perhaps there is anything wrong with the script?

Comment: In that case there could be 2 possible issues, either your `ajaxForm` is not being called or there is some error in the PHP script. To check if the call is made add a line `beforeSubmit: function(){alert("MAKING AJAX CALL")}` and in your success call back just do an alert of `data`. Also in your php script `return json_encode(["hello" => "world"])`

Comment: the Ajax call alert showed up after clicking the button, so the `ajaxForm` is working correctly isn't ? and calling the data with `data` fails to show the hello world alert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110253/discussion-between-nazhirin-imran-and-dwijen).